# Selecting child div by id knowing a parent div id with JQuery selectors

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have this html:

```
<div id="top">
<div id="potato"></div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
<div id="potato"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to use JQuery to access the bottom potato div, and none of the following work.

```
$('#top #potato').html('Russet');
$('#bottom #potato').html('Red');

$('#top > #potato').html('Russet');
$('#bottom > #potato').html('Red');

$('#potato').html('Idaho');
```

All of these just modify the top div and not the bottom one. How do I modify the bottom div?

Comment: @Matthew Is there answer here? Why don't  you follow your question?

Answer (score 25):

All elements must have unique IDs, in this case you may use the class attribute, so that you have

```
<div class="potato" />
```

Which you may access like this:

```
$('#bottom > .potato').html('Idaho');
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you're using variables, eg: $(a > b), It only for CSS selector statements. The $(a).find(b) syntax is more reliable for multiple situations.

Answer (score 20):

I just ran into this problem. Although it's true you shouldn't have two items with the same ID, it happens.

To get the div you want, this is what works for me:

```
$('#bottom').find('#potato');
```

Answer (score 5):

For one thing you can not have an element that has the same **id** as another. Id is unique, but class names can be used as many times as you want

```
<div id="top">
 <div id="potato1"></div>
</div>
 <div id="bottom">
 <div id="potato2"></div>
</div>
```

jquery as so:

```
$(function{
 $("#potato2").html('Idaho'); //if you're going to name it with an id, 
  //  that's all the selector you need
});
```

Comment: For other selectors, take a look at:http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors for examples

Answer (score 4):

What you posted and said doesn't work seems to work to me.

```
$('#top #potato').addClass('Russet');
$('#bottom #potato').addClass('Red');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wzezr706/

Answer (score 1):

no need to put classes on everything, but you should have unique id's for everything. That aside, try this:

```
$("#bottom + div").html('Idaho');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#bottom #potato").html('Idaho');
```

Or

```
$("#bottom #potato:last").html('Idaho');
```

Answer (score -1):

your HTML is not valid, since you have non-unique `id`s